# When I login on my app and pressed back im going back to my login page

Tags: android

I have this code where when a user logs in and pressed back it still goes back to the login page. Can somebody help me here? Here is my code

### Login

```
package com.example.kun.carkila;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
final String LOG = "MainActivity";
Button btnLogin;
EditText etUsername, etPassword;
TextView tvRegister;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirstname);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    tvRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegister);


    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HashMap postData = new HashMap();
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            postData.put("username", username);
            postData.put("password", password);

            PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, postData,
                    new AsyncResponse() {
                        @Override
                        public void processFinish(String s) {

                            if (s.contains("renterowner")) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Renter Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                                startActivity(in);

                            } else if (s.contains("ownerrenter")) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Owner Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ownerhome.class);
                                startActivity(in);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                        }
                    });
            task1.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/authenticate.php");
        }
    });

    tvRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Or I will modify the classes that will be redirected when i logged in?
Here are the redirected pages.

### ListActivity

```
package com.example.kun.carkila;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.amigold.fundapter.BindDictionary;
import com.amigold.fundapter.FunDapter;
import com.amigold.fundapter.extractors.StringExtractor;
import com.amigold.fundapter.interfaces.DynamicImageLoader;
import com.kosalgeek.android.json.JsonConverter;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private ArrayList<Cars> carList;
private ListView lvCars;
private FunDapter<Cars> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(ListActivity.this));
    PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(ListActivity.this, this);
    taskRead.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/product.php");

    lvCars = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCars);
    registerForContextMenu(lvCars);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    final Cars selectedCars = adapter.getItem(info.position);

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menuDelete) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setMessage("Do you want to remove " + selectedCars.Car_Model+ " ?");
        alert.setPositiveButton("Remove", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                carList.remove(selectedCars);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        alert.show();
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

    @Override
    public void processFinish (String s){

    carList = new JsonConverter<Cars>().toArrayList(s, Cars.class);

    BindDictionary<Cars> dict = new BindDictionary<Cars>();

    dict.addDynamicImageField(R.id.ivImg, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return product.Image;
        }
    }, new DynamicImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void loadImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageView); // Default options will be used
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCarModel, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Car Model: " + product.Car_Model;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCarType, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Car Type: " + product.Car_Type;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCapacity, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Capacity: " + product.Capacity;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvFuelType, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Fuel Type: " + product.FuelType;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvPlateNumber, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Plate Number: " + product.PlateNumber;
        }
    });
    adapter = new FunDapter<>(
            ListActivity.this, carList, R.layout.layout_list, dict);

    lvCars.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvCars.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

       Cars selectedCars = carList.get(position);
       Intent in = new Intent(ListActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
       in.putExtra("cars", selectedCars);
       startActivity(in);

}
}
```

And the other

### ownerhome

```
package com.example.kun.carkila;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class ownerhome extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ownerhome);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(ownerhome.this, InsertActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Thank you guys in advance. :)

Comment: use finish() in loginButton click

Comment: Thanks sir! This helped a lot. @VishalPatoliya

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
finish();
```

Does it exits immediately or completes the function from which it was called ?
The method that called finish() will run to completion. The finish() operation will not even begin until you return control to Android.
**Shared Preferance**
Find [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

it help for you

Comment: Thanks sir!! This helped a lot.

Comment: Sir, if it also possible that if i pressed the app again my logged in account is still logged on? Thanks

Comment: Just check user if user login or not. In case user login redirect to listactivity.

Comment: Uhm, how to check sir? Hahaha, i feel ashamed of asking. I'am a beginner programmer btw. :)

Comment: use sharedpreferences to store login status, on base of that redirect to login or listactivity